# Uri constructor with dontEscape is obsolete, what is alternatieve?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, escaping, uri

My question is regarding passing an URL to HttpWebRequest without escaping, I searched the forums and internet, but I didn't find a good solution for it.

I have following URL:`string URL= www.website.com/sub/redirec\t\bs\dd`

So when I create an uri like this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(URL);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

In this case on a get method I will get following URL:`www.website.com/sub/redirect%5Ct%5Cbc%5Cdd`

This sign "\" will be replaced by "%5C". What is crucial for me not to happen?

I can avoid that by:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(URL, true); //bool dontEscape
```

But this constructor is obsolete. How to have same effect without using obsolete?

Comment: Your URL is not a valid URI. Use *UriBuilder* to construct a URI with the correct protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
Uri uri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString(URL));
```

Comment: Now quite. Try this: `Uri uri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString("http://example.com?param=emai%2Btag%40gmail.com"));` Does not work