# A URL Encoded URI in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm attempting to make a web request through a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a Windows Phone 8.1 Application. The web request contains a set of search terms, which whilst building the request signature are percent encoded as such: `OAuthTools.UrlEncodeStrict(searchTerms)`, this is done because the search terms likely contain spaces. I then add all other parameters, and generate a signature. The request URL will then look something like this:

```
http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api?format=json&max_results=10&method=recipes.search&oauth_consumer_key=******&oauth_nonce=ksoordxpd5oahp9e&oauth_signature=Uxq3pmkTkRrASO%2Bmoiujs24BtT4%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1420634671&oauth_version=1.0&page_number=0&search_expression=pumpkin%20pie
```

As you can see, the final parameter, `search_expression=pumpkin%20pie` is encoded correctly. However, when putting this URL into a URI object (as the [WebClient.DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202(v=vs.110).aspx) method requires), the URL is decoded to:

```
http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api?format=json&max_results=10&method=recipes.search&oauth_consumer_key=******&oauth_nonce=ksoordxpd5oahp9e&oauth_signature=Uxq3pmkTkRrASO%2Bmoiujs24BtT4%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1420634671&oauth_version=1.0&page_number=0&search_expression=pumpkin pie
```

Removing the escaped spacing for the `search_expression` parameter. This results, in this case, in an invalid OAuth signature (as the parameters change), but using an unescaped search_expression with spaces also results in an invalid OAuth signature (I assume because REST parameters should not contain spaces). Is there a way to ensure that the URI class does not decode my URL string? I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10415482/159341) explaining that a workaround is to include:

```
<uri>
  <schemeSettings>
    <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
  </schemeSettings>
</uri>
```

Inside of the Web.config or App.config file. However, there appears to be no suitable config file to place this in inside a Windows Phone 8.1 development environment (I have tried adding it to packages.config and the app manifest, neither of which had any effect). Is there another way around this issue? Or alternatively, is there another way I can send a web request using a raw string, as opposed to through a URI object?

Comment: This looks like a nice solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759034/uri-constructor-with-dontescape-is-obsolete-what-is-alternatieve

Comment: How do you know it's being incorrectly encoded? When you create your `Uri`, what does `uri.AbsoluteUri` give you?

Comment: Hmm, ok, so the problem appears to be elsewhere. The absolute URI is correct, however I still get an invalid OAuth signature error (this works fine for searches with no spaces in).

Comment: @user3750097 Are you sure you should be signing the escaped representation?

Comment: @spender As far as I know, yes. The [API documentation](http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=rapiauth#create_signature_base) states to encode the signature base , and it works perfectly for a single search term. I'll try without escaping the search expression, just to check.