# New Uri but keep the spaces escaped

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

When creating a new instance of an Uri the spaces in the string are escaped with %20.

`new Uri("https://www.test.com?city=New York")`
will be converted into:
`https://www.test.com?city=New%20York`

However the other way:
`new Uri("https://www.test.com?city=New%20York")`
will be converted into:
`https://www.test.com?city=New York`

Is it possible to do not unescape when creating a new Uri? In other words, I'd like to keep
`https://www.test.com?city=New%20York` in the second example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uri constructor with dontEscape is obsolete, what is alternatieve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759034/uri-constructor-with-dontescape-is-obsolete-what-is-alternatieve)

Comment: Well why don't you replace %20 before like: `new Uri(str.Replace("%20"," "))`

Comment: @MathewHD Not really. When using `Uri.EscapeUriString(URL)` it will adjust the url into `https://www.test.com/?city=New%2520York`

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Then is indeed possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yk38Yd)

If you run the following code, you can get the escaped input:

```
string x = "https://www.test.com?city=New%20York";
Uri url = new Uri(x);

Console.WriteLine("written to string: " + url.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("query: " + url.Query);
Console.WriteLine("AbsoluteUri: " + url.AbsoluteUri);
Console.WriteLine("OriginalString: " + url.OriginalString);
```

This is the sample output:

```
written to string: https://www.test.com/?city=New York
query: ?city=New%20York
AbsoluteUri: https://www.test.com/?city=New%20York
OriginalString: https://www.test.com?city=New%20York
```

Comment: This is using .NET 5 in the fiddle